# Is the number of nodes for Zookeeper independent of the number of nodes for cluster to be monitored?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have never used Zookeeper and I am a little it confused on how many nodes I have to create. Indeed, I am wondering if the number of nodes for a Zookeper cluster is dependent of the number of nodes for the cluster to be minotored by Zookeeper. For instance, let's imagine I have a Hadoop cluster composed with K nodes (K>3). Do I have to set at least K nodes for my Zookeeper cluster ?

However, the zookeeper website says that I need to have 2N +1 nodes where N=number of failures to manage.

If the number of nodes for Zookeeper is independent, thus, I can have a hadoop cluster with 100 nodes and 3 nodes for Zookeeper where Zookeeper can only manage 1 failure.

I hope my question is clear.
I would be very thankful for any kind of help, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ZooKeeper nodes is independent.  As you surmised, the `2N+1` rule applies to the number of ZooKeeper node failures you can tolerate.